# Cannot open database "NitgenAccessManager" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection, jtds

I'm using jtds and I'm trying to connect my java application to a *Microsoft SQL Server 2005*. Below is my connection URL.

> jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.158.176:1433/NitgenAccessManager;
>   instance=SQLEXPRESS; user=sa;password=password

I'm trying to do a remote connection (DB server is in a different computer).

Whenever I try to run the program I get the following error:

> Cannot open database "NitgenAccessManager" requested by the login. The
>   login failed.

I'v read the different posts concerning this same problem and I've tried their suggested solutions but none worked.

Thanks for future help. :)

Comment: I tried a different driver. This time I used sqljdbc instead of jdbcjtds. I ended up with the same error. I hope someone might provide some help :\

Answer (score 0):

One of the following (assuming that you connecting as `sa`:

- DB **NitgenAccessManager** does not exists
- DB **NitgenAccessManager** is not online (suspect, recovery and so on)